# Store List of objects in Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, session-variables

I want to store the result of the query called by the controller in a variable

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Session["dateDebut"] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Session["dateFin"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        HostClassReq hostClassChart = new HostClassReq();
        Chart_Event cex = new Chart_Event();

        var viewModel = new Chart_Event
        {
            chartVM = hostClassChart.callHostClass()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Here is the methode callHostClass implementation

```
    public Highcharts callHostClass()
    {
        DateTime begin = DateTime.ParseExact(HttpContext.Current.Session["dateDebut"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(HttpContext.Current.Session["dateFin"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddDays(1);
        CreateChart createChart = new CreateChart();
        List<String> xs = new List<string>();





        var maListe = (from p in db.exclure
                      where (p.type.Contains("Host Class"))
                      group p by p.libelle into g
                      select new
                      {
                          libellex = g.Key
                      }).ToList();

        List<string> strListe = new List<string>();

        foreach (var x in maListe.Select(i => i.libellex))
        {

            strListe.Add(x.ToString());
        }



           var   myList = (from p in db.Full
                      where ( (p.date_reception > begin & p.date_reception < end & !p.mc_host_class.Contains("NULL")) &

                   (!strListe.Contains(p.mc_host_class)))
                      group p by p.mc_host_class into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select new
                      {
                          hostclassx = g.Key,
                          countx = g.Count()
                      }).Take(10).ToList();



       //  HttpContext.Current.Session["allList"] = myList;
         List<Full> questions = (List<Full>)HttpContext.Current.Session["allList"];

       //  questions = List <Full> myList;
         foreach (var x in questions)
         {

         }



         object[] ys =  myList.Select(a => (object)a.countx.ToString()).ToArray();






        foreach (var x in myList.Select(i => i.hostclassx))
        {
            if (x.Length > 20)
            {
                xs.Add((x.Substring(0, 20)));
            }
            else
            {
                xs.Add(x);
            }

        }



        var chart = createChart.createChartBar(xs, ys, 10);

        return chart;


    }
```

I need to store the result of myList query in a variable that will be accessed by another classes i need some help.

Comment: `.ToList().Take(10);` can produce some performance issues. You fetch all entities into memory and then take 10 first. You could take first 10 on the db side and then fetch it into memory with `ToList()`.

Comment: Please how to do it, i'm new to asp mvc

Comment: You need to order main query and then replace `ToList` with `Take`: `.Take(10).ToList()`. Ordering is required to use `Take` or `Skip`.

Comment: that's helpful thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
Session["yourName"]=myList;
```

**EDIT** After question edit emerged that he wanted to use session in a class not extending Controller.

**NEW PART**

Therefore you can't use the initial suggestion but instead include System.Web `using System.Web;` and use

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["yourName"]=myList;
```

When you have to get it you use

```
var yourList = (myListType)Session["yourName"];
```

if you are in a class extending Controller or

```
var yourList = (myListType)HttpContext.Current.Session["yourName"];
```

otherwise.

Comment: I tried it the told me Sessio does not exist in the current context, i'm trying to use it in a methode that is called by the controller

Comment: did you enable session in web.config?

Comment: i didnt know about that but i use sessions in controller without any probleme

Comment: what's your mvc version?

Comment: can you enhance your Q with controller and action code? Because I tried and works in my case (MVC5 EF6).

Comment: is there a way to share my code because number of caracters is limited

Comment: Here is it sir, i want to store result of myList in some variable that will be kept and used in another class.

Comment: Of course you cant use Session["yourName"]=yourValue. You are doing that in a class not extending Controller so you don't have Session :) this wasn't specified in initial question. Ok I'll update my answer, where exactly do you want to read from Session["yourList"]? In Index before return View?

Comment: I want to get it from another class createChart that takes values from myList and draw the chart

Comment: My problem is in the cast (myList), myList returns string and int values, how can i deal with them ?

Comment: you get what you stored :) the question was about how to use session and I explained it with example. If you now have a question about your LINQ query that populates 'myList' you should open a specific question.

Comment: Glad to have been useful to you. I'll check your next question and try to help as well. I think you should accept answer to close this question now ;) see you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] = mylist;
```

But be careful accessing session like that, might cause null-ref exceptions

Comment: the probleme is that it doesnt have the same variable type as mylist, for example i cant use   object[] ys = HttpContext.Current.Session["name"].Select(a => (object)a.countx.ToString()).ToArray(); , but i can use   object[] ys = myList.Select(a => (object)a.countx.ToString()).ToArray();